# How do I simulate a POST request in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am working on a script to process credit cards and the company that process the payments will check the user ip, country, etc of the post request.

Lets say I have the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://payment-processing-company.com/process_payment.php">
<input type="text" name="card_holder" value="John Doe">
<input type="text" name="creditcard_number" value="65415461171">
<input type="text" name="vcc" value="123">
<input type="text" name="exp_date" value="15/02/2017">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

In the above example the user makes a POST action request directly to http://payment-processing-company.com/process_payment.php to process the payment and payment-processing-company.com will grab his IP, country, etc.

What I want is simulate the POST request **action="http://payment-processing-company.com/process_payment.php"** in a php file and when user press submit button Simulate with his real ip, country.

Please do not recommend any javascript/ajax submit. What I want is hide the action POST action url from the source code and process it when user press submit button in a PHP file all with his real IP, country, etc SIMULATED ALL IN PHP

Comment: You can't click a different button and end up on a different form action **without using javascript**. There are numerous ways to handle this situation, from building a small proxy that detects whether `Send` or `Simulate` where clicked on the server side to having simple JS altering values on the fly. But since you don't want it, and it appears this task is way above your skill level - good luck with it.

Comment: what if I put. process.php in the action with an header ("Location: http://payment-processing-company.com/process_payment.php") inside process.php

Comment: Why don't you try it and check what happens? I did comment you could build a small proxy, do you know what that is?

Answer (score 6):

The quick way is to use `curl` command

```
curl --data "card_holder=value1&creditcard_number=value2" http://payment-processing-company.com/process_payment.php
```

Another way is with Chrome extension such as [Postman - REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

You can send a POST request from PHP using cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$params = array(
    "card_holder"=>"a",
    "creditcard_number"=>"b",
    "vcc"=>"c",
    "exp_date"=>"d",
);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://paymentprocessingcompany.com/process_payment.php");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($params));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//result will contain the response
```

Comment: with your code it simulates the post request with real user ip, user agent, etc? anyways I'll test your code on my test server

Comment: tested, it will send a request with the server ip not the real user ip. thank you anyways

Comment: @up ofcourse as the server is the one sending the quest. We are talking about PHP here after all. If you want the user-IP to be sent as sender from a curl-request you have to do this using JavaScript / Ajax request or write your own PHP-curl library where you can spoof any ip into your request but I think the first solution will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

In order to establish a connection to the remote (payment) server, you need to complete a [three-way TCP handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.4). The handshake is completed when your server responds with a reference to a sequence number returned by the remote server. Even if you manage to [spoof the original users IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing), this sequence number will be sent back to *that* IP address and not to your server.

While it has been shown in the past that IP addresses could be spoofed by [guessing the remote servers sequence numbers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1948), this is very unlikely to work today as this bug was fixed years ago.

---

So no, you can not spoof the users IP address in anything that is run on your server. If you need to use the users IP address, you have to perform the form action on the *users computer*, eg. using Javascript.

**Or**, you could contact the payment service to find out if you can pass the IP address, country et cetera as additional parameters in the `POST` request from your server.